# PHPで月末の金曜日かどうか判定する方法

Tags: php

PHPで月末の金曜かどうか判定する方法を教えてください。

Carbonで曜日の判定はできるが、第◯週の◯曜日といった判定はできない？ぽい・・

```
$date = "YYYY-MM-DD" 
$test = strtotime("last fri of this month", strtotime($date));
```

上記コードでYYYY-MM-DDの最終金曜は呼び出せます。
これで`$test`と`$date`を
`if($test === $date)`で比較すれば良いと思いますか？

Comment: この記事あたりでしょうか？ [Get the First or Last Friday in a Month](https://stackoverflow.com/q/924246/9014308)

Answer (score 2):

とても良いと思います。
もしくは今日が金曜日かつ翌週が翌月を判定する方法もあります。

```
<?php
$date = strtotime("2021/06/25");

// 月末の金曜と比較
if($date == strtotime("last fri of this month", $date)) {
    echo "最終金曜日です。\n";
}

// 曜日比較 && 現在の月と翌週の月を比較
if(date('w', $date) == 5
   && date('m', $date) != date('m', strtotime("+1 week", $date))) {
    echo "最終金曜日ですってば。\n";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

> Carbonで曜日の判定はできるが、第◯週の◯曜日といった判定はできない？ぽい・・

`Carbon` を使う場合です。

```php
<?php

require 'Carbon/autoload.php';

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Carbon\CarbonPeriod;

$day = '2021-07-15';
// $day = Carbon::now();
$period = CarbonPeriod::between(
    Carbon::parse("first fri of {$day}"),
    Carbon::parse("last fri of {$day}"),
  )->weeks();

foreach ($period as $date) {
  $fridays[] = $date->format('Y-m-d');
}

echo implode(PHP_EOL, $fridays) . PHP_EOL;
echo PHP_EOL;

$last = Carbon::parse("last day of {$day}")->subDays(3);
$month = $last->format('Y/n');
foreach (range(0, 2) as $offset) {
  $date = $last->addDays(1)->format('Y-m-d');
  echo "{$date} is " .
    ($date == end($fridays) ? '' : 'not ') .
    "last friday of {$month}" . PHP_EOL;
}

# 実行結果
2021-07-02
2021-07-09
2021-07-16
2021-07-23
2021-07-30

2021-07-29 is not last friday of 2021/7
2021-07-30 is last friday of 2021/7
2021-07-31 is not last friday of 2021/7
```